Too Many Arguments Error in Hardhat Test for NFT Marketplace Contract
I'm encountering an issue with my Hardhat test for an NFT marketplace contract, where I'm  getting this error while calling the buyItem function in my test file:
Nft Marketplace Unit Tests
       buyItem
         transfers the nft to the buyer and updates internal proceeds record:
     Error: too many arguments: passed to contract (count=1, expectedCount=0, code=UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0) 

Also, both the contracts are deployed without errors and just the "transfers the nft to the buyer and updates internal proceeds record" test fails.
Relevant Smart Contract Code
Here's the relevant portion of my Solidity contract:
function buyItem(address nftAddress, uint256 tokenId) external payable isListed(nftAddress, tokenId) {
    Listing memory listing = s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
    if (msg.value < listing.price) {
        revert NFTmarket_NotEnoughPrice(listing.price);
    }
    s_proceeds[listing.seller] += msg.value;
    delete s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
    IERC721 nft = IERC721(nftAddress);
    nft.safeTransferFrom(listing.seller, msg.sender, tokenId);
    emit ItemBought(nftAddress, tokenId, msg.value, msg.sender);
}

Relevant Test Code
Here's the relevant portion of my Hardhat test file:
it("transfers the nft to the buyer and updates internal proceeds record", async function () {
    await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)

    nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
    await expect(
        await nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, {
            value: PRICE,
        })
    ).to.emit(nftMarketplace, "ItemBought")

    const newOwner = await basicNft.ownerOf(TOKEN_ID)
    assert(newOwner === user.address, "Ownership not transferred correctly")

    const deployerProceeds = await nftMarketplace.getProceeds(deployer.address)
    assert(
        deployerProceeds.toString() === PRICE.toString(),
        "Proceeds not updated correctly"
    )
})

Full Smart Contract Code
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity 0.8.25;
import  "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

/*
1.listing
2.buying
3.updating price
4.delete listing
5.withdraw proceeds
 */
error NFTmarket_PriceCannotBeZero();
error NFTmarket_NotApproved();
error NFTmarket_AlreadyListed(address nft,uint256 tokenId);
error NFTmarket_NotListed(address nft,uint256 tokenId);

error NFTmarket_NotOwner(address nft,uint256 token,address owner);
error NFTmarket_NotEnoughPrice(uint256 value,address sender);
error NFTmarket_transferFailed(address sender,uint256 proceeds);
error NFTmarket_NoProceeds();
contract NFTmarket{
    //contract  variables
    struct Listing{
        address seller;
        uint256 price;

    }
    mapping(address=>mapping(uint256 => Listing)) private s_listings;
    mapping(address=>uint256) private s_proceeds;
    //events
    event ItemListed(address indexed nft, uint256 indexed tokenId, uint256 price,address sender);
    event ItemBought(address indexed nftAddress,uint256 indexed tokenId,uint256 price,address buyer);
    event ItemCanceled(address indexed nftAddress,uint256  indexed tokenId  );  
    
    //constructor

    //modifiers
    modifier alreadyListed(address nft,uint256 tokenId) {
        Listing memory listing = s_listings[nft][tokenId];

        if(listing.price>0){
            revert NFTmarket_AlreadyListed(nft,tokenId);
        }
        _;

    }
    modifier isListed(address nft,uint256 tokenId) {
        Listing memory listing = s_listings[nft][tokenId];

        if(listing.price<=0){
            revert NFTmarket_NotListed(nft,tokenId);
        }
        _;

    }
    modifier isOwner(address nftAdd,uint256 tokenId,address owner){
        IERC721 nft = IERC721(nftAdd);
        if(nft.ownerOf(tokenId) != owner){
            revert NFTmarket_NotOwner(nftAdd,tokenId,owner);
        }
        _;
            
        }
    
    //main functions
    function listItem(address nftAddress,uint256 tokenId,uint256 price) isOwner(nftAddress,tokenId,msg.sender) alreadyListed(nftAddress,tokenId) external {
        if(price<=0){
            revert NFTmarket_PriceCannotBeZero();
        }
        IERC721 nft = IERC721(nftAddress);
        if(nft.getApproved(tokenId)!= address(this)){
            revert NFTmarket_NotApproved();
        }
        s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId] = Listing(msg.sender,price);
        emit ItemListed(nftAddress,tokenId,price,msg.sender);
    }

    function buyItem(address nftAddress,uint256 tokenId)   isListed(nftAddress,tokenId) public payable{
        Listing memory listing = s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
        if(msg.value<listing.price){
            revert NFTmarket_NotEnoughPrice(msg.value,msg.sender);
        }
        s_proceeds[listing.seller] = s_proceeds[listing.seller] + msg.value;
        delete s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
        IERC721 nft = IERC721(nftAddress);
        nft.safeTransferFrom(listing.seller,msg.sender,tokenId);
        emit ItemBought(nftAddress,tokenId,msg.value,msg.sender);


    }

    function cancelListing(address nftAddress,uint256 tokenId) external isListed(nftAddress,tokenId) isOwner(nftAddress,tokenId,msg.sender) {
        delete s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
        emit ItemCanceled(nftAddress,tokenId  );  
    }

    function updateListing(address nftAddress,uint256 tokenId,uint256 price) external isListed(nftAddress,tokenId) isOwner(nftAddress,tokenId,msg.sender){
        if(price<=0){
            revert NFTmarket_PriceCannotBeZero();
        }
        s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId].price =price;
        emit ItemListed(nftAddress,tokenId,price,msg.sender);
    }

    function withdraw() external payable{
        uint256 proceeds = s_proceeds[msg.sender];
        if(proceeds==0){
            revert NFTmarket_NoProceeds();
        }
        delete (s_proceeds[msg.sender]);
        (bool send,) = payable(msg.sender).call{value:proceeds}("");
        if(!send){
            revert NFTmarket_transferFailed(msg.sender,proceeds);
        }
    }

    //view functions
    
    function getListing(address nft,uint256 id) view external returns(Listing memory)
    {
        return s_listings[nft][id];
    }

    function getProceeds() external view returns(uint256){
        return s_proceeds[msg.sender];
    }
}


Full Test Code
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { network, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

async function getContract(contract) {
    const myContract = await deployments.get(contract)
    return await ethers.getContractAt(myContract.abi, myContract.address)
}

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Nft Marketplace Unit Tests", function () {
          let nftMarketplace, basicNft, deployer, user
          const PRICE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")
          const TOKEN_ID = 0

          beforeEach(async () => {
              const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
              deployer = accounts[0]
              user = accounts[1]
              await deployments.fixture(["all"])
              nftMarketplace = await getContract("NFTmarket")
              basicNft = await getContract("BasicNFT")
              await basicNft.mintNft()
              await basicNft.approve(nftMarketplace.address, TOKEN_ID)
          })

          describe("listItem", function () {
              it("emits an event after listing an item", async function () {
                  await expect(nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)).to.emit(
                      nftMarketplace,
                      "ItemListed"
                  )
              })

              it("exclusively allows owners to list", async function () {
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
                  await basicNft.approve(user.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_NotOwner")
              })

              it("requires approvals to list item", async function () {
                  await basicNft.approve(ethers.constants.AddressZero, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_NotApproved")
              })

              it("exclusively items that haven't been listed", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  const error = `NFTmarket_AlreadyListed("${basicNft.address}", ${TOKEN_ID})`
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith(error)
              })

              it("reverts if the price is 0", async () => {
                  const ZERO_PRICE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0")
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, ZERO_PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_PriceCannotBeZero")
              })
          })

          describe("cancelListing", function () {
              it("reverts if there is no listing", async function () {
                  const error = `NFTmarket_NotListed("${basicNft.address}", ${TOKEN_ID})`
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.cancelListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith(error)
              })

              it("reverts if anyone but the owner tries to call", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
                  await basicNft.approve(user.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.cancelListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_NotOwner")
              })

              it("emits event and removes listing", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  await expect(nftMarketplace.cancelListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)).to.emit(
                      nftMarketplace,
                      "ItemCanceled"
                  )
                  const listing = await nftMarketplace.getListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  assert(listing.price.toString() == "0")
              })
          })

          describe("buyItem", function () {
              it("reverts if the item isn't listed", async function () {
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_NotListed")
              })

              it("reverts if the price isn't met", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_NotEnoughPrice")
              })

              it("transfers the nft to the buyer and updates internal proceeds record", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)

                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
                  await expect(
                      await nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, {
                          value: PRICE,
                      })
                  ).to.emit(nftMarketplace, "ItemBought")

                  const newOwner = await basicNft.ownerOf(TOKEN_ID)
                  assert(newOwner === user.address, "Ownership not transferred correctly")

                  const deployerProceeds = await nftMarketplace.getProceeds(deployer.address)
                  assert(
                      deployerProceeds.toString() === PRICE.toString(),
                      "Proceeds not updated correctly"
                  )
              })
          })

          describe("updateListing", function () {
              it("must be owner and listed", async function () {
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.updateListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_NotListed")
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.updateListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_NotOwner")
              })

              it("reverts if the new price is 0", async function () {
                  const updatedPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("0")
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.updateListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, updatedPrice)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NFTmarket_PriceCannotBeZero")
              })

              it("updates the price of the item", async function () {
                  const updatedPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.2")
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.updateListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, updatedPrice)
                  ).to.emit(nftMarketplace, "ItemListed")
                  const listing = await nftMarketplace.getListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  assert(listing.price.toString() == updatedPrice.toString())
              })
          })

          describe("withdrawProceeds", function () {
              it("doesn't allow 0 proceed withdrawals", async function () {
                  await expect(nftMarketplace.withdraw()).to.be.revertedWith(
                      "NFTmarket_NoProceeds"
                  )
              })

              it("withdraws proceeds", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(user)
                  await nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, {
                      value: PRICE,
                  })
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplace.connect(deployer)

                  const deployerProceedsBefore = await nftMarketplace.getProceeds()
                  const deployerBalanceBefore = await deployer.getBalance()
                  const txResponse = await nftMarketplace.withdraw()
                  const transactionReceipt = await txResponse.wait(1)
                  const { gasUsed, effectiveGasPrice } = transactionReceipt
                  const gasCost = gasUsed.mul(effectiveGasPrice)
                  const deployerBalanceAfter = await deployer.getBalance()

                  assert(
                      deployerBalanceAfter.add(gasCost).toString() ==
                          deployerProceedsBefore.add(deployerBalanceBefore).toString()
                  )
              })
          })
      })



The error is due to the argument that you're passing while executing the getProceeds function in your "transfers the nft to the buyer and updates internal proceeds record" test, because it doesn't expect any argument as per its definition in the contract i.e.,
function getProceeds() external view returns (uint256) {
    return s_proceeds[msg.sender];
}

So, replace this line in your test:
const deployerProceeds = await nftMarketplace.getProceeds(deployer.address)

With:
const deployerProceeds = await nftMarketplace.getProceeds()


thanks a lot. I was focused on await nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, {
value: PRICE,
}) that i ignored the rest

No worries. Yeah, it happens with all of us. Happy coding!
